# C# Encrypt/Decrypt AES-256-CBC with PBKDF2 from OpenSSL

Tags: c#, openssl, cryptography

I've made a encryption/decryption of a string by using openssl command line:

#Encrypt

> echo "test" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -pbkdf2 -md sha256 -pass pass:"12345"
> Encrypted output: U2FsdGVkX18s7uM/ydI4ER7zb939KShMxpvJ9aqeL2g=

#Decrypt

> echo "U2FsdGVkX18s7uM/ydI4ER7zb939KShMxpvJ9aqeL2g=" | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -pbkdf2 -md sha256 -pass pass:"12345"
> Decrypted output: test

Then, I've wrote bellow function code in c# to encrypt:

```
public string Encrypt(string plainText, string password)
{
  var salt = new byte[8];
            
  password = Hash(password);
            
  byte[] pwd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

  derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd, salt, 10000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);            
                        
  byte[] k = derivedBytes.GetBytes(32);
  byte[] iv = derivedBytes.GetBytes(16);                           

  using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
  aes.KeySize = 256;
  aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
  aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
  aes.Key = k;
  aes.IV = iv;

  // Encrypt
            
  ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
            
  byte[] text = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);

  byte[] cipherText = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(text, 0, text.Length);


  return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
}


public static string Hash(string input)
{
            // Use input string to calculate hash
   using (System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256 md = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create())
   {
       byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
       byte[] hashBytes = md.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

       // Convert the byte array to hexadecimal string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
          {
            sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
          }

      return sb.ToString().ToLower();
   }
}
```

But, the function output is different from desired output. Thus, if I try to decrypt from openssl command line, the result is "bad magic number".

What's sounds wrong in above code?

I've tried change the Hash encoding to SHA256 or MD5, but none have worked.

Comment: The ciphertexts are different not least because OpenSSL generates a random salt for each encryption. There are also other differences in the logic: In the C# code, `hash(password)` is additionally generated and the (Base64 encoded) OpenSSL formatting of prefix, salt and ciphertext is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the working routine in c# for encrypt exactly according to OpenSSL command line:

The main changes was in password hash transform and a replace of ICryptoTransform to CryptoStream. Then, the code worked like expected.

```
public static string EncryptString(string plaintext, string password)
{
    byte[] plaintextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);

    byte[] salt = GenerateRandomBytes(8);
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];
    byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];

    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 10000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
    {
        keyBytes = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
        ivBytes = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(16);
    }

    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = keyBytes;
        aesAlg.IV = ivBytes;
        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length);
            }

            byte[] encryptedBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            byte[] encryptedData = new byte[8 + salt.Length + encryptedBytes.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Salted__"), 0, encryptedData, 0, 8);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, encryptedData, 8, salt.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedData, 8 + salt.Length, encryptedBytes.Length);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        }
    }
}


public static byte[] GenerateRandomBytes(int length)
{
    using (RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        byte[] randomBytes = new byte[length];
        rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
        return randomBytes;
    }
}
```